Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0 - SSIS C# Script Task
I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to fix this issue. I'm trying to run a VS Studio 2015 SSIS Script Task with the Newtonsoft.Json.dll. I've tried adding it via GACUTIL, NUGET Package Manager, browsing/selecting assembly. No matter what I do, and no matter what version I tie too,  it still gives me an error at runtime "Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0". Here is my code which is basically a copy of other code snippets:
try
    {
        var clientId = Variables.User;
        var clientSecret = Variables.Password;
        var authenticationString = $"{clientId}:{clientSecret}";
        //MessageBox.Show(authenticationString);
        var base64EncodedAuthenticationString = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(authenticationString));
        //MessageBox.Show(base64EncodedAuthenticationString);
        string serviceUrl = "https://myapplication.com";
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(serviceUrl);
        // Add an Accept header for JSON format. 
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", base64EncodedAuthenticationString);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        string APIUrl = string.Format(serviceUrl + "/search-svc/datarequest/runReport?format=xml&report=USERNAME_LOOKUP");

        var response = client.GetAsync(APIUrl).Result;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var result = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<HttpResponseMessage>().Result;
            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                //TODO update your database based on the result      
            }
            //Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
    }

I installed version 13.0.3
This is the path to the DLL: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Newtonsoft.Json\v4.0_13.0.0.0__30ad4fe6b2a6aeed\Newtonsoft.Json.dll
I updated the assembly binding to:
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-13.0.0.0" newVersion="13.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>      
</assemblyBinding>

I don't know why it is looking for version 6.0.0.0 and how to change it.

try cleaning the solution then open up the VS dev terminal an run the following command:  dotnet restore then rebuild the solution.  see if that helps.
